# Ruby: transform Hash-Keys

Tags: ruby

I have a Hash:

```
urls = [{'logs' => 'foo'},{'notifications' => 'bar'}]
```

The goal is to add a prefix to the keys:

```
urls = [{'example.com/logs' => 'foo'},{'example.com/notifications' => 'bar'}]
```

My attempt:

```
urls.map {|e| e.keys.map { |k| "example.com#{k}" }}
```

Then I get an array with the desired form of the keys but how can I manipulate the original hash?

Comment: You don't have a hash. You have an array of hashes, single-element hashes at that. If this is actually how your data is being stored it's not a good use of either the array or the hash, and suggests this is an XY Problem where you should be asking about how to generate the structure instead of how to manipulate the keys. "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968)"

Comment: Also, it looks like you're trying to build hostnames/paths or URLs. If so, be aware that the URI spec requires some characters to be encoded and people usually get that wrong then wonder why their links don't work. Ruby's [URI](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html) class provides setters and getters to make it easier to create correct strings and is the simple, easy and correct way to generate them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to "manually" transform the keys, then you can first iterate over your array of hashes, and then over each object (each hash) map their value to a hash where the key is interpolated with "example.com/", and the value remains the same:

```
urls.flat_map { |hash| hash.map { |key, value| { "example.com/#{key}" => value } } }
# [{"example.com/logs"=>"foo"}, {"example.com/notifications"=>"bar"}]
```

Notice urls are being "flat-mapped", otherwise you'd get an arrays of arrays containing hash/es.

If you prefer to simplify that, you can use the built-in method for for transforming the keys in a hash that Ruby has; [`Hash#transform_keys`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys):

```
urls.map { |url| url.transform_keys { |key| "example.com/#{key}" } }
# [{"example.com/logs"=>"foo"}, {"example.com/notifications"=>"bar"}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`transform_keys`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/Hash/transform_keys).

```
urls = [{'logs' => 'foo'}, {'notifications' => 'bar'}]
urls.map { |hash| hash.transform_keys { |key| "example.com/#{key}" } }
# => [{"example.com/logs"=>"foo"}, {"example.com/notifications"=>"bar"}]
```

One question: are you best served with an array of hashes here, or would a single hash suit better? For example:

```
urls = { 'logs' => 'foo', 'notifications' => 'bar' }
```

Seems a little more sensible a way to store the data. Then, saying you did still need to transform these:

```
urls.transform_keys { |key| "example.com/#{key}" }
# => {"example.com/logs"=>"foo", "example.com/notifications"=>"bar"}
```

Or to get from your original array to the hash output:

```
urls = [{'logs' => 'foo'}, {'notifications' => 'bar'}]
urls.reduce({}, &:merge).transform_keys { |key| "example.com/#{key}" }

# => {"example.com/logs"=>"foo", "example.com/notifications"=>"bar"}
```

Much easier to work with IMHO :)

Comment: Agreed that the original data shouldn't be an Array of Hashes, it should be single Hash, hence my comment to the OP about it being an XY Problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to `Hash#transform_keys` i.e. Ruby < 2.5.5 this should work:

```
urls.map{ |h| a = h.to_a; { 'example.com/' + a[0][0] => a[0][1] } }
```